# "sudo apt update" and all I get is (target content is configured multiple times), (the repository does not have a Release file), (404 not found)

Tags: ubuntu, updates, sudo, updating, apt

this is my first time to install linux on my system, I think there is a lot of mess here and I feel helpless from too many errors I got when trying to update my system, when use terminal with this command:

```
sudo apt update
```

I got many errors specially from these 3 types:

1. (target content is configured multiple times)
2. (the repository does not have a Release file)
3. (Err 404 not found)

knowing that I searched many topics and couldn't solve the problem with my system.

Here's the output I got after writing "sudo apt update"

```
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412) zesty InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412) zesty Release
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign:3 http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable  InRelease                
Ign:4 http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org artful InRelease                
Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:6 http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable  Release                  
Ign:7 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                      
Hit:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                     
Hit:9 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                              
Hit:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                    
Ign:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease              
Hit:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                    
Ign:13 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease             
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu artful InRelease        
Hit:15 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                    
Err:16 http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org artful Release                 
  Connection failed [IP: 82.195.75.101 80]
Ign:17 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease           
Err:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release                
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease [81.7 kB]  
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu artful InRelease       
Hit:21 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                     
Err:22 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Hit:23 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                  
Err:24 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu zesty InRelease        
Err:26 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Hit:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dansmith/chirp-snapshots/ubuntu artful InRelease
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease [72.2 kB]
Hit:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/diesch/testing/ubuntu artful InRelease         
Hit:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/eugenesan/ppa/ubuntu artful InRelease          
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease [78.6 kB] 
Hit:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu artful InRelease   
Hit:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net/i2p-maintainers/i2p/ubuntu artful InRelease   
Hit:35 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu artful InRelease       
Hit:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu zesty InRelease        
Hit:37 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu artful InRelease
Hit:38 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser-testing/ubuntu artful InRelease
Hit:39 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu artful InRelease         
Hit:40 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu artful InRelease
Hit:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu artful InRelease
Hit:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/peterlevi/ppa/ubuntu artful InRelease         
Hit:43 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmjdebruijn/darktable-release/ubuntu artful InRelease
Hit:44 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu artful InRelease
Hit:46 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:47 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu artful InRelease         
Hit:48 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu zesty InRelease          
Hit:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu artful InRelease      
Hit:50 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:51 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/brackets/ubuntu artful InRelease
Hit:52 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/brackets/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:53 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu artful InRelease
Hit:54 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:55 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu artful InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412) zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Contents-deb (main/Contents-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-stable.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error/warning output of repository update command is related to your repository settings. The settings reside inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/<file>` and `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

First of all you should comment out all repositories located at *cdrom* since you really don't want to use packages out of your CD-ROM installation media...

The rest of errors is related to either unsecure connection (plain HTTP) or just the repository being dead (404, Release file). You should probably do the same as with the *cdrom* ones - comment them out.

Comment: thanks my friend, but excuse me I'm still new with linux, how to comment out repositories located at cdrom

Comment: Open and edit the repository settings files. Disable all repositories pointing to the `cdrom` by prepending a comment mark. The comment mark is `#` as stated in the docs https://linux.die.net/man/5/sources.list.

Answer (score 11):

The output is simply a warning that you have the same entry in the main sources.list file and in a special file named google-chrome.list.
You can live with it or remove the file, as it is unneeded.

To do so, open a terminal and run

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then run

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Hope it's help you.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, and here's the error that was been displayed multiple times

```
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-amd64/Packages)
is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 
and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list:4
```

I fixed it this way

1. Enter the command below in your terminal

   `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Comment out the line that is causing the issue.
3. Save your changes.

Answer (score 0):

bash version to fix this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the target entries you want to remove duplicates for
targets=("Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages)" "Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages)" "Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages)" "Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US)" "Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en)" "Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml)" "Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml)" "Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar)" "Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar)" "Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar)" "Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64)" "Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all)" "Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages)" "Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages)" "Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages)" "Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US)" "Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en)" "Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml)" "Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml)" "Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar)" "Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar)" "Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar)" "Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64)" "Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all)")

# Loop through the targets and remove duplicates
for target in "${targets[@]}"; do
    grep -F "$target" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | awk '!x[$0]++' > /tmp/sources.list
    cat /tmp/sources.list > /etc/apt/sources.list
done

# Clean up temporary file
rm /tmp/sources.list

echo "Duplicates removed successfully."
```

you may need to change the name of the apt list, so use at your own discretion.

Answer (score -1):

Or... Just turn off your VPN. Run

> sudo apt update

This should give you normal results. Seems that VPN's & Proxies almost disturb updates.

Comment: What makes you think that a 404 and missing Release files on a repo is caused by a VPN?